# Jquery Tooltips lag/duplicate on close elements

Tags: jquery, html

I've got tool tips that are not disappearing correctly (IE They lag after you move to the next element)

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadMap(x, y,z);
    $(document).tooltip({
        at: 'center top',
        my: 'center bottom'
        });
    if(z != 0)
    {
        $('#map').addClass('hell'); 
    }
    upgrade();
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class='upgrade' id='technology' title='tech'>tech 16 <br />$101,538</div>
<div class='upgrade' id='economy' title='econ'>econ 14 <br />$19,600</div>
<div class='upgrade' id='medicine' title='medicine'>medicine 14 <br />$13,069</div>
<div class='upgrade' id='biology' title='biology'>biology 9 <br />$6,480</div>
<div class='upgrade' id='offense' title='offense'>offense 5 <br />$1,450,369</div>
<div class='upgrade' id='defense' title='defense'>defense 13 <br />$3,782,340</div>
</div>
```

When you move the mouse from on upgrade to the next, the previous one either stays on the previous div or overlapse the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this,

```js
        $("document").tooltip({
            position:{
              at: 'center top',
              my: 'center bottom'
            }
        });
```